# How can a non-trivial analytic function be homogeneous by its Taylor series?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

Assume we have a non-trivial (i.e., not of the form $f(x)=cx^k$) homogeneous function $f(\lambda x)=\lambda^k f(x)$ for some integer degree $k$. If such a function were analytic, there must be a local Taylor expansion for it (e.g., at $0$), i.e., $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. This is of course trivially satisfied by $f(x)=cx^k$, but can there be a non-trivial example? I would guess not, because of the sum, but it still is an infinite series so I am not 100% sure.

Comment: You don't need Taylor expansion to prove this. Suppose $f$ is defined at some point $t \in \Bbb{R}$ (or $t \in \Bbb{C}$) and $t \ne 0$. Then for any $x$, $f(x)=f(\dfrac{x}{t} \cdot t)=\left( \dfrac{x}{t} \right)^k f(t) = \dfrac{f(t)}{t^k} \cdot x^k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(\lambda x)=\lambda^k f(x)$$
interchanging $\lambda$ and $x$,
$$f(\lambda x)=x^k f(\lambda)$$
sub $\lambda=1$
$$f(x)=f(1) x^k$$